# How is Clausius statement violated for reversible heat engines that are assumed to have different efficiencies?

Tags: physical-chemistry, heat

[image]

I'm trying to verify that all reversible heat engines have equal efficiencies by using this diagram. Here, the second heat engine (HE2) is assumed to has higher efficiency than the first heat pump (HP1). Since W2 > W1, some work produced by the HE2 can be used for other work, which is denoted as W2 - W1. This concludes that the overall engine will be extracting heat energy from the low temperature reservoir and completely convert it to work (W2 - W1 = Q2 - Q2'), which violates Kelvin-Planck's statement.

What I'm having trouble is, I don't get how Clausius statement (heat doesn't flow spontaneously from cold to hot regions) is violated here? Can someone help?